Qt can't detect MSVC compiler with studio 2022
i am facing same problem, can any one assist please ?
simmilar to previously asked question :
Qt can't detect MSVC compiler.
visual studio 2022 installed.
and below is cmake version -
C:\Users\admin\source\repos>cmake.exe --version
cmake version 3.27.7
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
I am not able to figure it out why not able to detect compiler.
below are my screenshot :





Is the question you linked to also your question? If so please don't post duplicate question, edit the original if you have new details to add

Looks to me like this question ought to be closed as a duplicate of the question you link to..

@AlanBirtles no, not my question, but facing same scenario and tried the solution but didnt worked for me

as you have a very old version of Qt built for VS 2015 it probably isn't compatible with VS 2022, you should download a newer version or at least one built for VS 2022

You must select the required compilation environment in the installer:

In Qt Creator, It seems that only MSVC2019 is supported for Qt 6, MSVC2015-MSVC2019 for Qt 5.
Official online installer
